# SQL Earliest/Latest times query

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to only grab the earliest time and latest time from a query that grabs all times for a user who has logged into a system and then logs out.  Current query grabs multiple times and some of them are duplicates for an indvidual user I only want two times.  Earliest and Las

Current query looks like this:

```
select distinct uas.user_name,   
to_char(uas.access_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS ADATE  
,case      
    when lower(uas.WAS_NODE_NM) Like '%p1pta%' then 'CC1'      
    when lower(uas.WAS_NODE_NM) Like '%p3pta%' then 'CC3'    
end as LOCATION  
,case  
    when to_char(uas.access_time, 'hh24:mi:ss') between '11:10:00' and '11:30:00' then 'Early'  

    when to_char(uas.access_time, 'hh24:mi:ss') between '12:40:00' and '13:00:00' then 'Late'   

    end as AUCTION   
    ,uas.ORG_NAME  
    ,uas.USER_URL  
    ,to_char(uas.ACCESS_TIME, 'hh24:mi:ss.ff2') as "Access Time"  
    From PCTAP.user_audit uas  

  where uas.access_time >= '12-DEC-18'   

  order by ADATE, LOCATION,uas.USER_NAME
```

Comment: Hello Bob, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Are you looking for the earliest and last times for each user for each day?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Kyle Mac, please excuse me.  I dont have an IT background so I may seem sort of dumb on some of these questions.  Glad you didnt ask me a hard one.  What I am trying to accomplish is determining a feasible time to take a system down for upgrades, maintenance etc.  I am trying to find a time where user are at a minimum.  So when a user logs into the system, it tracks everywhere they go in the application with a timestamp.  so there are multiple timestamps.  I need to know the initial log in and log out.  Dont care what they did in between.

Comment: I am using SQL Developer